# Is NetMQ compatible with ZMTP 1.0?

Tags: zeromq, netmq

Does anybody knows if NetMQ is compatible with ZMTP 1.0? I can't find any information about what versions is supported.

Answer (score 3):

It should support it, but I suggest you test it.

Comment: Thank you. It seems to not work. At least I cant make NetMQ talk to zeromq 2.* running on OpenVMS. I can see that TCP-sockets connects but no data is transfered. Is there some handshaking taking place after TCP socket is connected? If yes, where can I find this function in the sourcecode?

Comment: BTW I can connect if I use clrzmq.

Comment: Thank you. But we will probably take a different path. We try to use a newer version on the other side and that seems to fix our issues. Otherwise I will create an isse on github.